# How to find page object to access iframe inside div in watir

Tags: ruby, ui-automation, watir-webdriver

```
I want to find a page-object for an Iframe that is inside div element.

<html>
Iframe inside the div element
<div name=first>
    <iframe> 
    </iframe>
</div>
<div name=second>
    <iframe>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I tried finding div_element and start accessing the iframe, but i'm getting undefined method.

Could anyone help us to identify and access the page-object for iframe inside div?

Answer (score 1):

The page object gem does not have a nested element method for frames/iframes. You will need to find a locator that can uniquely identify the frame/iframe with respect to the browser (or another frame/iframe). The only locators that support relative position to other elements are `:css` and `:xpath`.

Note that the page object gem does not hold references to a frame/iframe object (ie there are no nested element calls like in Watir). Instead, frames are passed as part of the locators for the element.

As an example, let's consider the following HTML, which adds (inline for brevity) some frame content:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div name="first">
      <iframe src="frame1.htm">
        <html>
          <body>
            <span>frame1 - span</span>
            <input type="text" name="field" value="1" />
          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <div name="second">
      <iframe src="frame2.htm">
        <html>
          <body>
            <span>frame2 - span</span>
            <input type="text" name="field" value="2" />
          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Depending on what you are interacting with, you either access the iframe contents using an accessor or defining a method. The following page object uses accessor methods. Remember to pass the frame locator to each element.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  # Define elements <div name="first"> iframe
  in_iframe(css: 'div[name="first"] iframe') do |f|
    span(:first_iframe_span, frame: f)
    text_field(:first_iframe_field, frame: f)
  end

  # Define elements <div name="second"> iframe
  in_iframe(css: 'div[name="second"] iframe') do |f|
    span(:second_iframe_span, frame: f)
    text_field(:second_iframe_field, frame: f)
  end
end
```

You can see that each defined element returns the value from the specific iframe:

```
# Elements in the <div name="first"> iframe
p page.first_iframe_span
#=> "frame1 - span"
p page.first_iframe_field
#=> "1"

# Elements in the <div name="second"> iframe
p page.second_iframe_span
#=> "frame2 - span"
p page.second_iframe_field
#=> "2"
```

You can dynamically access elements in a method using a similar approach:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  def do_stuff_in_first_iframe
    in_iframe(css: 'div[name="first"] iframe') do |f|
      p span_element(frame: f).text
      p text_field_element(frame: f).value
    end
  end

  def do_stuff_in_second_iframe
    in_iframe(css: 'div[name="second"] iframe') do |f|
      p span_element(frame: f).text
      p text_field_element(frame: f).value
    end
  end
end
```

Which again, you can see that you get values for each iframe:

```
page.do_stuff_in_first_iframe
#=> "frame1 - span"
#=> "1"

page.do_stuff_in_second_iframe
#=> "frame2 - span"
#=> "2"
```

Comment: Actually i need to access the elements (input,div) inside the iframe, eg., 
<html>
Iframe inside the div element
<div name=first>
    <iframe>
      <input>
       <div></div>
    </iframe>
</div>
<div name=second>
    <iframe>
    </iframe>
</div>

and not the div element that is present outside the iframe.

Comment: That is exactly what this code is doing. It is accessing a div element within the iframe.

Comment: Actually I need to access the iframes inside div

Comment: Yes, this code is doing that too. The code says to find the `div` element with a specific name - ie "first" or "second". Then within that `div`, find the `iframe`. Finally, within that `iframe` access an element. I updated my example to hopefully be more clear. If this is not what you are looking for, I would suggest giving a more concrete example - ie the exact HTML you want to interact with and exactly what element you want.

Comment: Hi @Justin Ko, May i know what is the use of **iframe** inside the in_iframe?
   in_iframe(css: 'div[name="second"] iframe') do |f|

Comment: `iframe` is needed in the CSS-selector since the `in_frame` method is expecting to locate an `iframe` element. In English, the CSS-selector is saying, "find the div element with a name attribute value of "second", then within that div find an iframe".

Comment: Okay, Is there any way to locate that iframe with any particular attributes like id/class ? @Justin ko

Comment: Yes. `in_iframe` will accept any of the standard locators (eg id, name, class). If those attribute values are unique for the page, then you can drop the :css locator. If you still need to locate the iframe with respect to the div, then you can include those attributes in the css-selector.

Comment: I thought of access the common div like,
    `div(common_div) do |page|
      if page.div_element(id: 'brief', frame: fr_main).visible?
        page.div_element(id: 'brief', frame: fr_main)
      elsif page.div_element(id: 'intake', frame: fr_main).visible?
        page.div_element(id: 'intake', frame: fr_main)
      end
    end`
I tried to access the Iframe inside the div in below method,
    `in_iframe({ css: 'ob_section', id: 'common-iframe' }, fr_main) do |ifr_main|
     text_field(:text_f, name: 'text_search', frame: ifr_main)
    end`

Will that work?

Comment: There may be syntax errors in that code - eg `css: 'ob_section'` is not likely what you want (ie looking for an element of type "ob_section"). Conceptually, I am not sure what you are trying to do with that code. Are you saying you need to find the iframe based on which div is visible? But if there is a single frame with an id, why is the div relevant? I really think you need to update the question to provide the exact HTML/CSS structure that you are trying to work with.